# How to vertically align input fields to have the same width regardless of the sibling element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I have an issue stacking input fields and keeping them with the same width depending on the screen size (flex) when the next sibling of the input is omitted.

HTML

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <input class="item1" />
    <div class="item2">something</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <input class="item1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .parent {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   flex: 1;
 }

 .item1 {
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid grey;

 }

 .item2 {
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

The input field "item1" without the "item2" element takes the entire width of the parent but want it perfectly aligned with the above "item1". I can do that by providing an "item2" and hiding it but would like to avoid that.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fsdhrv7b/2/)

Comment: while you need to align col and rows Its a job for grid not flex : https://jsfiddle.net/L7k9e2ph/1/

Comment: yea will go with grid... wanted to find a solution with flex but would just indroduce hacks..

Answer (score 0):

Make two columns and put both .item1 and .item1 in the first, and put .item2 in the second one. You can then use `flex-direction: row` for the colums and `flex-direction: column` inside first column.

Comment: I guess you are refering to grid  for columns which also I cannot use...

Comment: No, I was talking about flexbox.